# how do json decode in php?

Tags: php, json, decode

I have the following json string and I want to retrieve just the email address from it. How do I do it in php?

```
[{"username":"23441","username":"vanthien","phone":"0293029230"},{"username":"23442","username":"hoangtung","phone":"0599799930"},
{"username":"23443","username":"thanhtung","phone":"069929230"},
{"username":"23444","username":"redlight","phone":"0293299230"},]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an email address. Other than that: json_decode($string).

Comment: This seems like [something you could easily search for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json+decode+in+php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's JSON functions are documented here: https://www.php.net/json

The `json_decode()` function may be especially useful: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

So, first off, your JSON isn't valid.  You can copy and paste it into a site like

http://jsonlint.com/

to help with that.  (You have a trailing comma at the end.  The other issue is, you have two entries for "username" on each entry (a number and then a string), so the first is going to get overwritten by the second.  Thirdly, if you are looking for an email address, your JSON doesn't contain any email addresses.  I'll assume you meant username.

Below is some code that iterates through your JSON and prints out the value of username.

```
<?php
$json = '[{"username":"23441","username":"vanthien","phone":"0293029230"},{"username":"23442","username":"hoangtung","phone":"0599799930"},
{"username":"23443","username":"thanhtung","phone":"069929230"},
{"username":"23444","username":"redlight","phone":"0293299230"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json);
//echo print_r($arr, true);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
  echo $value->username . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you validate your json and have an email address to extract you can use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$parsed = json_decode($json, true);
```

Using the **true** flag will create an associative array

```
$email= $parsed['email'];
```